# How to refresh webpage after submitting contact from in HTML?

Tags: php, html, ajax, web, contact-form

***How to refresh webpage after submitting contact from in HTML?***
I have a .html page and I am sending email from html contact form using ajax. When I click on submit button the form data has been submitted and the page moves on mail.php. I want that after form submission my contact.html page gets reload and appears it not to move on mail.php

Comment: Please show your code.

Comment: you need to use ajax on the form. to get relevant help, please paste your code.

Answer (score 0):

```
$('#form_contact').submit(function(e){

    e.preventDefault();

    var data = $(this).serialize();

    $.ajax({

        url: 'mail.php?form_contact',
        data: data,
        type: 'post',
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function(r)
        {

            location.reload();

        }
    });
});
```

Comment: Is this use on .html page or any other?

Comment: Yes this is a javascript. Put it below your html